# Problems validating XML with RelaxNG-schema

Tags: xml, validation, relaxng, xmlschemaset

I'm having trouble validating my XML up against my RelaxNG-schema. I am a bit new to relaxng, so excuse me if the fault is obvious.

Jing produces three types of errors when validating:

Error 1: "element "article" not allowed here; expected element "chapter""

Error 2: "element "article" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag"

Error 2 "element "chapter" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag"

the XML-file:

```
<?xml-model href="publications.rng" type="application/xml" 
schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<publications>
<book>
    <title>group agency: the possibility, design, and status of corporate 
agents</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <publisher>oxford university press</publisher>
    <cited>598</cited>
    <published>2011</published>
</book>

<article>
    <title>aggregating sets of judgments: an impossibility result</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <journal>economics and philosophy</journal>
    <volume>18</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>89-110</pages>
    <cited>558</cited>
    <published>2002</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>social choice theory and deliberative democracy: a reconciliation</title>
    <author>js dryzek</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>british journal of political science</journal>
    <volume>33</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>1-28</pages>
    <cited>479</cited>
    <published>2003</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>epistemic democracy: generalizing the condorcet jury theorem</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>re goodin</author>
    <journal>journal of political philosophy</journal>
    <volume>9</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>277-306</pages>
    <cited>409</cited>
    <published>2001</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>judgment aggregation: a survey</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>c puppe</author>
    <collection>handbook of rational and social choice</collection>
    <cited>240</cited>
    <published>2009</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>arrow’s theorem in judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>29</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>19-33</pages>
    <cited>220</cited>
    <published>2007</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>aggregating sets of judgments: two impossibility results compared</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <journal>synthese</journal>
    <volume>140</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>207-235</pages>
    <cited>203</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>the discursive dilemma and public reason</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>ethics</journal>
    <volume>116</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>362-402</pages>
    <cited>154</cited>
    <published>2006</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>deliberation, single-peakedness, and the possibility of meaningful democracy: evidence from deliberative polls</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>rc luskin</author>
    <author>js fishkin</author>
    <author>i mclean</author>
    <journal>journal of politics</journal>
    <volume>75</volume>
    <number>(01)</number>
    <pages>80-95</pages>
    <cited>143</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>judgment aggregation by quota rules: majority voting generalized</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>journal of theoretical politics</journal>
    <volume>19</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>391-424</pages>
    <cited>130</cited>
    <published>2007</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>disaggregating deliberation's effects: an experiment within a deliberative poll</title>
    <author>c farrar</author>
    <author>js fishkin</author>
    <author>dp green</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>rc luskin</author>
    <author>el paluck</author>
    <journal>british journal of political science</journal>
    <volume>40</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>333-47</pages>
    <cited>129</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>the theory of judgment aggregation: an introductory review</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>synthese</journal>
    <volume>187</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>179-207</pages>
    <cited>124</cited>
    <published>2012</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a model of path-dependence in decisions over multiple propositions</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>american political science review</journal>
    <volume>98</volume>
    <pages>495-514</pages>
    <cited>124</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>strategy-proof judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>economics and philosophy</journal>
    <volume>23</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>269</pages>
    <cited>123</cited>
    <published>2007</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>non-reductive physicalism and the limits of the exclusion principle</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p menzies</author>
    <journal>journal of philosophy</journal>
    <volume>106</volume>
    <number>(9)</number>
    <pages>475-502</pages>
    <cited>106</cited>
    <published>2009</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>democracy in animal groups: a political science perspective</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>trends in ecology and evolution</journal>
    <volume>19</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>168-169</pages>
    <cited>98</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a reason‐based theory of rational choice</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>nous</journal>
    <volume>47</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>104-134</pages>
    <cited>95</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>judgment aggregation without full rationality</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>31</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>15-39</pages>
    <cited>95</cited>
    <published>2008</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>group agency and supervenience</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <journal>the southern journal of philosophy</journal>
    <volume>44</volume>
    <number>(s1)</number>
    <pages>85-105</pages>
    <cited>87</cited>
    <published>2006</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>the probability of inconsistencies in complex collective decisions</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>24</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>3-32</pages>
    <cited>82</cited>
    <published>2005</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>group knowledge and group rationality: a judgment aggregation perspective</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>episteme</journal>
    <volume>2</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>25-38</pages>
    <cited>79</cited>
    <published>2005</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a model of jury decisions where all jurors have the same evidence</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>synthese</journal>
    <volume>142</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>175-202</pages>
    <cited>77</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>corrigendum to "a possibility theorem on aggregation over multiple interconnected propositions" [mathematical social sciences 45 (2003), 1-13]</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>mathematical social sciences</journal>
    <volume>52</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>109-110</pages>
    <cited>73</cited>
    <published>2006</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a possibility theorem on aggregation over multiple interconnected propositions</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>mathematical social sciences</journal>
    <volume>45</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>1-13</pages>
    <cited>73</cited>
    <published>2003</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>two concepts of agreement</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>the good society</journal>
    <volume>11</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>72-79</pages>
    <cited>73</cited>
    <published>2002</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>methodological individualism and holism in political science: a reconciliation</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>k spiekermann</author>
    <journal>american political science review</journal>
    <volume>107</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>629-643</pages>
    <cited>71</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>introduction to judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>b polak</author>
    <journal>journal of economic theory</journal>
    <volume>145</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>441-466</pages>
    <cited>71</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>on the many as one: a reply to kornhauser and sager</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <journal>philosophy and public affairs</journal>
    <volume>33</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>377-390</pages>
    <cited>62</cited>
    <published>2005</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>where do preferences come from?</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>international journal of game theory</journal>
    <volume>42</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>613-637</pages>
    <cited>61</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>can there be a global demos? an agency‐based approach</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>m koenig-archibugi</author>
    <journal>philosophy and public affairs</journal>
    <volume>38</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>76-110</pages>
    <cited>57</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>majority voting on restricted domains</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>journal of economic theory</journal>
    <volume>145</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>512-543</pages>
    <cited>56</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a conditional defense of plurality rule: generalizing may's theorem in a restricted informational environment</title>
    <author>re goodin</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>american journal of political science</journal>
    <volume>50</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>940-949</pages>
    <cited>54</cited>
    <published>2006</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>in defence of voting power analysis: responses to albert</title>
    <author>ds felsenthal</author>
    <author>d leech</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>m machover</author>
    <journal>european union politics</journal>
    <volume>4</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>473-497</pages>
    <cited>46</cited>
    <published>2003</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>free will, determinism, and the possibility of doing otherwise</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>noûs</journal>
    <volume>48</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>156-178</pages>
    <cited>43</cited>
    <published>2014</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a liberal paradox for judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>31</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>59-78</pages>
    <cited>42</cited>
    <published>2008</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>social choice theory</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <collection>stanford encyclopedia of philosophy</collection>
    <cited>40</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>group communication and the transformation of judgments: an impossibility result</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>journal of political philosophy</journal>
    <volume>19</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>1-27</pages>
    <cited>39</cited>
    <published>2011</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>the causal autonomy of the special sciences</title>
    <author>p menzies</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <collection>emergence in mind</collection>
    <editors>
        edited by: c. mcdonald and g. mcdonald</editors>
    <cited>39</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>republican freedom and the rule of law</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>politics, philosophy and economics</journal>
    <volume>5</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>201-220</pages>
    <cited>39</cited>
    <published>2006</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>on the significance of the absolute margin</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>the british journal for the philosophy of science</journal>
    <volume>55</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>521-544</pages>
    <cited>33</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>propositionwise judgment aggregation: the general case</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>40</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>1067-1095</pages>
    <cited>32</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<book>
    <title>deliberation and decision: economics, constitutional theory and deliberative democracy</title>
    <author>a van aaken</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>c luetge</author>
    <publisher>ashgate pub ltd</publisher>
    <cited>31</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</book>

<article>
    <title>are interpersonal comparisons of utility indeterminate?</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>erkenntnis</journal>
    <volume>58</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>229-260</pages>
    <cited>30</cited>
    <published>2003</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>mentalism versus behaviourism in economics: a philosophy-of-science perspective</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <collection>economics and philosophy</collection>
    <cited>27</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>a simple proof of sen's possibility theorem on majority decisions</title>
    <author>c elsholtz</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>elemente der mathematik</journal>
    <volume>60</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>45-56</pages>
    <cited>19</cited>
    <published>2005</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>aggregating causal judgements</title>
    <author>r bradley</author>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>philosophy of science</journal>
    <volume>81</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>491-515</pages>
    <cited>17</cited>
    <published>2014</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>emergent chance</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>m pivato</author>
    <journal>the philosophical review</journal>
    <volume>124</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>119-152</pages>
    <cited>15</cited>
    <published>2015</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>the impossibility of unbiased judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>theory and decision</journal>
    <volume>68</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>281-299</pages>
    <cited>15</cited>
    <published>2010</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>reason-based choice and context-dependence: an explanatory framework</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>economics and philosophy</journal>
    <volume>32</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>175-229</pages>
    <cited>14</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>collective wisdom: lessons from the theory of judgment aggregation</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <collection>ccollective wisdom: principles and mechanisms</collection>
    <cited>14</cited>
    <published>2012</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>multidimensional welfare aggregation</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>public choice</journal>
    <volume>119</volume>
    <number>(1-2)</number>
    <pages>119-142</pages>
    <cited>14</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>craig's theorem and the empirical underdetermination thesis reassessed</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>disputatio</journal>
    <volume>7</volume>
    <pages>28-39</pages>
    <cited>14</cited>
    <published>1999</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>when to defer to supermajority testimony—and when not</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <collection>essays in collective epistemology</collection>
    <cited>13</cited>
    <published>2014</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>"deliberative polling" als methode zum erlernen des demokratischen sprechens</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>a sliwka</author>
    <journal>zeitschrift für politik</journal>
    <volume>51</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>87-105</pages>
    <cited>10</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
    <language>german</language>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>the methodology of political theory</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>
        valentini</author>
    <collection>the oxford handbook of philosophical methodology</collection>
    <cited>8</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>introduction to the special issue of economics and philosophy on neuroeconomics</title>
    <author>g bonanno</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>b tungodden</author>
    <author>p vallentyne</author>
    <journal>economics and philosophy</journal>
    <volume>24</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>301-302</pages>
    <cited>8</cited>
    <published>2008</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>social choice theory and deliberative democracy: a response to aldred</title>
    <author>js dryzek</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>british journal of political science</journal>
    <volume>34</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>752-758</pages>
    <cited>8</cited>
    <published>2004</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>a note on introducing a “zero‐line” of welfare as an escape route from arrow’s theorem</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>pacific economic review</journal>
    <volume>6</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>223-238</pages>
    <cited>7</cited>
    <published>2001</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>episteme symposium on group agency: replies to gaus, cariani, sylvan, and briggs</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p pettit</author>
    <journal>episteme</journal>
    <volume>9</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>293</pages>
    <cited>5</cited>
    <published>2012</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>probabilistic opinion pooling generalized: part two: the premise-based approach</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>social choice and welfare</journal>
    <volume>48</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>787–814</pages>
    <cited>4</cited>
    <published>2017</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>two intuitions about free will: alternative possibilities and intentional endorsement</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>w rabinowicz</author>
    <journal>philosophical perspectives</journal>
    <volume>28</volume>
    <number>(1)</number>
    <pages>155-172</pages>
    <cited>4</cited>
    <published>2014</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>independence and interdependence: lessons from the hive</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>a vermeule</author>
    <journal>rationality and society</journal>
    <volume>26</volume>
    <number>(2)</number>
    <pages>170-207</pages>
    <cited>4</cited>
    <published>2014</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>reasons for (prior) belief in bayesian epistemology</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>synthese</journal>
    <volume>190</volume>
    <number>(5)</number>
    <pages>787-808</pages>
    <cited>4</cited>
    <published>2013</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>freedom as independence</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>l valentini</author>
    <journal>ethics</journal>
    <volume>126</volume>
    <number>(4)</number>
    <pages>1043-1074</pages>
    <cited>3</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</article>

<article>
    <title>belief revision generalized: a joint characterization of bayes' and jeffrey's rules</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>r bradley</author>
    <journal>journal of economic theory</journal>
    <volume>162</volume>
    <pages>352–371</pages>
    <cited>3</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>my brain made me do it: the exclusion argument against free will, and what’s wrong with it</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>p menzies</author>
    <collection>making a difference</collection>
    <editors>
        edited by: h. beebee, c. hitchcock, and h. price</editors>
    <cited>3</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</chapter>

<article>

    <title>what matters and how it matters: a choice-theoretic representation of moral theories</title>
    <author>f dietrich</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <journal>philosophical review</journal>
    <volume>0</volume>
    <pages>0</pages>
    <cited>2</cited>
    <published>2017</published>
</article>

<chapter>
    <title>the condorcet jury theorem and voter-specific truth</title>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>k spiekermann</author>
    <collection>goldman and his critics</collection>
    <cited>2</cited>
    <published>2016</published>
</chapter>

<article>
    <title>introduction to the special issue of economics and philosophy on ambiguity aversion</title>
    <author>g bonanno</author>
    <author>m van hees</author>
    <author>c list</author>
    <author>b tungodden</author>
    <journal>economics and philosophy</journal>
    <volume>25</volume>
    <number>(3)</number>
    <pages>247-248</pages>
    <cited>2</cited>
    <published>2009</published>
</article>

</publications>
```

The Relaxng schema for the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar 
xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
<start>
        <element name="publications">

                    <element name="book">
                        <element name="title"><text/></element>                                                                                                
                                <oneOrMore>
                                    <element name="author"><text/></element>                          
                                </oneOrMore>                                    
                        <element name="publisher"><text/></element>                           
                        <element name="cited"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                        <element name="published"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="gYear"/></element>
                        <zeroOrMore>
                            <element name="language"><text/></element>
                        </zeroOrMore>                        
                    </element> 

                    <element name="article">
                        <element name="title"><text/></element>                     
                                <oneOrMore>  
                                    <element name="author"><text/></element>                          
                                </oneOrMore>                                
                        <element name="journal"><text/></element>       
                        <element name="volume"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                        <optional>
                        <element name="number"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="string"></data></element>
                        </optional>
                        <element name="pages"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="string"/></element>
                        <element name="cited"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                        <element name="published"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                        <zeroOrMore>
                            <element name="language"><text/></element>
                        </zeroOrMore>
                    </element>

            <element name="chapter">

                <element name="title"><text/></element>
                <oneOrMore>     
                    <element name="author"><text/></element>            
                </oneOrMore>
                <element name="collection"><text/></element>
                <zeroOrMore>
                    <element name="editors"><text/></element>
                </zeroOrMore>
                <element name="cited"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                <element name="published"><data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes" type="int"/></element>
                <zeroOrMore>
                    <element name="language"><text/></element>
                </zeroOrMore>                            
            </element>                       
        </element>          
</start>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant files *here*. No external links to code snippets that aren't part of the question, because if the external link dies the question and the answer become usless to future readers.

Comment: Mats, as Tomalak pointed, please add a code snipper with the schema you are trying to use. Include versions and functional examples to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry. I added some of the XML, but the file is too large for the entire snippet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your XML does not match the schema because:

1. order of elements is defined as "book", "article", "chapter" - You have unordered elements.
2. I'm not familiar with RelaxNG-schema but in traditional XSD schema number of element occurrences must be defined (default min=1 max=1). It seems like your schema allows only one book, then one article, then one chapter.

So,

> Error 1: "element "article" not allowed here; expected element "chapter""

appears because there is second `<article>` after first but `<chapter>` expected.

> ```
> Error 2: "element "article" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag"
> Error 2 "element "chapter" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag"
> ```

appear because there are many articles, chapters and books after first book and first article...

Suggestions:

1. to use unordered elements - use XML Choice of book,article,chapter
2. define occurences of that choice as "many"

I know how to do it in XSD, but  for RelaxNG it is up to you...

Comment: Got it working now! Had to restructure some of the XML with a <publication>-tag surrounding each book, article and chapter. I then sat a constraint for oneOrMore publications, and a choice between each book, article and chapter. Thank you so much!